# unable to show success message after submitting a form using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am sending email using ajax after when ajax form is submitted.

Here is my php controller code:
If i keep the email sending code inside this function then the `SUCCESS` message is not showing on the html page. But if i remove the `Email sending` code from that function then `SUCCESS` message is showing.

```
public function  sendedits()
   {
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li  class="errorlist">', '</li>')->set_rules('menu_name', 'Title', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[255]|xss_clean');

        //user is logged in proceed the next work
           if (!$this->form_validation->run()) 
           {   //False  
               $this->_status['status'] = "error";
               $this->_status['message'] = $this->load->view('commonfiles/ajax_error_display_1', '', TRUE);
           } 

            else if ($this->form_validation->run() && $this->input->post('myId')=='')//myId=just for checking robot or human
             {      //TRUE block   
              $fname=$this->input->post('menu_name');
              $sendersemail=$this->input->post('changes_made');     
              $intrested_message=$this->input->post('content');   
               $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
               $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
               $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
               $config['smtp_user'] = 'asdsdsd@gmail.com';
               $config['smtp_pass'] = 'sdsfsdfsdfsdfsds'; 
               $this->load->library('email', $config);
               $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); 
               //$this->email->from($sendersemail, $fname);
               $this->email->to('ssdd@myemil.com');     
                    $this->email->subject('User Edited article of : '.$fname); 
                   $message = '<html>
                                       <head>
                                           <title></title>
                                           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                                       </head>
                                       <body>
                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:98%;background-color:whitesmoke" border="1">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                       <td colspan=2><h2> '.$fname.'</h2></td>
                                                </tr>  
                                                <tr>
                                                     <td width=50%>First  Name </td>
                                                      <td width=50%>'.$fname.'</td>
                                               </tr>      
                                               <tr>
                                                     <td width=50%>Email </td>
                                                      <td width=50%>'.$sendersemail.'</td>
                                               </tr>     

                                                    <tr>
                                                     <td width=50%>Message </td>
                                                      <td width=50%>'.$intrested_message.'</td>
                                               </tr>   </tbody> <table> </body></html>  ';
               $this->email->message($message); 
               $this->email->send(); 
              $this->_status['message'] = 'Thankyou for your edits. We will review it before publishing.'; 
               $this->_status['status'] = "success"; 
             } 
          echo json_encode($this->_status);    
   }
```

Ajax function for submitting the form

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var _status = $('#status');
        $('#sub2').click(function(e) {

            _status.html('');
            var postData = $('#form_id').serializeArray();
            var formURL = $('#form_id').attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(dat) {
                    if (dat.status === 'success') { 
                        _status.html('<span class="success">' + dat.message + '</span>');
                    }
                    else if (dat.status === 'fail') {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        _status.html('<span class="err">' + dat.message + '</span>');

                    }
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert("Ooops! Try again later or else sends us  message regarding this issue. Thankyou!");
                }
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Im guessing this is using the phpmailer library, do you have that installed (it might come as default depending on your platform)

The first thing that I can see is that `$sendersemail` is not defined. Try inserting a string instead of the variable. The phpmailer library is terrible for cactching errors, I can never figure out how to tell where the errors are either!

If that doesnt work, try outputting to the console after the line you think is giving you the error. If you use:

echo("email sent");

Then you should see it in the browser console as the code is being processed. Hopefully you can see where the error is coming from then.

Comment: Could you please post line 1362 from D:\xampp\htdocs\system\libraries\Email.php? (and a few of the surrounding lines)

Comment: Looks like the from field is definitely the issue. Have you tried inserting a string inside of the variable for the from field?

Comment: Maybe the from fields needs to be a valid email address?

Comment: Yes you are right `the from fields needs to be a valid email address`. sometime tiny mistake waste 3 hrs of my time